# Django query count unique NEW results per day

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm keeping statistics of my app in a database in a model that looks like this

```
class MyStats():
    event_code = django.db.models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    timestamp = django.db.models.DateTimeField()
    timestamp_date = django.db.models.DateField()
    device_id = django.db.models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

I would like to use this data to determine, for each day, how many NEW app installations I have.

I got as far as this:

```
MyStats.objects.order_by('-timestamp_date').values('timestamp_date').annotate(count_total=Count('device_id', distinct=True))
```

But what it seems to give me is the amount of unique users per DAY, which is not desired. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

"New" really means "Occurring after `x_timedelta` ago":

```
import datetime

x_timedelta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

x_timedelta_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - x_timedelta

your_query = MyStats.objects.filter(timestamp_date__gt=x_timedelta_ago)

your_query_distinct = your_query.order_by('-timestamp').annotate(count_total=Count('device_id', distinct=True)).values()
```

Comment: No. I was referring to new app installations, not new statistic entries. So the uniqueness of device_id also has to be taken into account.

Comment: @tdma does the above edit make more sense? Basically just adds your filter for distinct values...

Comment: No, what you are doing is filtering for unique USES today. I'm looking for a way to get the unique INSTALLS, which would be the unique uses for today, minus all device_id's that already generated records in the past.

Comment: @tdma when someone uses the app, does this overwrite the initial timestamp? The best way to achieve what you're looking for is to use something like [TimeStampedModel](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/model_extensions.html) and filter for the `created` field in the date range you want. If you keep overwriting the timestamp every time the user logs in, how could you differentiate the users who logged in for the first time today from those who logged in one week ago and then logged in again today?

Comment: Nothing gets overridden. New stats append.